# Matplotlib key_press_event never fires in macosx backend

Tags: matplotlib

I'm using Matplotlib with the `macosx` backend. I'm following the example [here](https://matplotlib.org/examples/event_handling/keypress_demo.html) to hook up a simple event handler:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def _on_keypress(event):
    print('Hit on_keypress()')

plt.connect('key_press_event', _on_keypress)
# Call plt.plot() a few times ... 
plt.show()
```

When I run this script from the terminal a figure is shown, but pressing keys shows the pressed key in the terminal, and `_on_keypress` is never called.

It seems like the plot window is somehow not in focus? Yet I get the same behavior (characters go to terminal) whether I click on the figure or the terminal.

If I open a debugger I can verify the handler is attached to the canvas:

```
(Pdb) fig = plt.gcf()
(Pdb) fig.canvas.key_press_event('a')
Hit on_keypress()
```

What is going on?

Comment: Do you use interactive mode (e.g. because you use IPython or by calling `plt.ion()`)?

Comment: No, interactive mode is not on. I DID also try it in interactive mode, and called `plt.pause(10000)` to get blocking behavior after the plot() calls above.  Same problem: `_on_keypress()` still wasn't called.

Comment: Then I have no idea. But it works with other backends, right?

Comment: It works for `Qt5Agg` at least, that's the only other one I tried

Comment: The code works fine for me. What version of python and matplotlib are you using? It maybe also important, how you have installed the packages.

Comment: Huh, very interesting. I'm using Python 3.6.6 and Matplotlib 2.1.2 on OSX 10.14.1, installed using Anaconda.

Comment: I'm on Python 3.6.7 with Matplotlib 3.0.1 and OSX 10.13.6 and both are installed using macports.